# Getting some sort of authentication issue when deploying EC2 instances with Knife

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I'm having some kind of authentication issue when trying to launch server instances in EC2 with the knife command.

I'm using a command like:

```
knife ec2 server create --availability-zone us-east-1d --node-name ES-test --flavor t1.micro --image ami-fd20ad94 --identity-file something-dev.pem --ssh-user ubuntu  -r 'recipe[something-elasticsearch::default]'
```

And there are 2 points of failure.  The first comes relatively early on.

```
Waiting for instance...........................
Subnet ID: subnet-61dfa849
Private IP Address: 10.0.0.43
done
Bootstrapping Chef on 10.0.0.43
Failed to authenticate ubuntu - trying password auth
Enter your password:
```

I should be able to authenticate as Ubuntu with no password here.  In fact, if I allow the provisioning to continue and try to ssh to the generated instance with something like:

```
ssh -i something-dev.pem ubuntu@10.0.0.43
```

...it will work.  So why is the knife command itself failing to authenticate?

Comment: Are you running that knife command in the same directory as your .pem file?

Comment: Chef is probably not using your private key `something-dev.pem` to login. Have you tried: `ssh-add something-dev.pem` or `mkdir -p ~/.ssh; cat something-dev.pem > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` from the machine where you are running knife ?

Comment: I tried doing ssh-add as well as adding the key to .ssh/authorized_keys and I'm still not getting anywhere.  Thank you for offering other things to try, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as above and tried the ssh-add as suggested by Rico above. Although I still got the prompt for a password, hitting enter on a blank password then allowed the process to continue.

Failing that, the -V verbose output option may give you more insight.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work well for me.

`bundle exec knife ec2 server create -r "role[websphere]" -I ami-cb94868e --flavor m1.small -G default --ssh-user ubuntu -N server01 -S whatever --identity-file .chef/whatever.pem`

Also consider that when you download the .pem from AWS, you need to `chmod 400 whatever.pem`